# Output of listview getItemAtPosition() method gives unreadable output

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My `listview` is from a layout where its id is `@android:id/list`. It is part of the `android.R.id.list`. I used a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to `setAdapter` to `listview`. The listview contains `checkboxes` with contact names such as Emily Andrews, Susan John... I wanted to know the names of the contacts which were selected by the user. When I use the code below, it prints an object `android.content.ContentResolver.cursorWrapper`... I am not sure how to interpret this and know which contact name was selected. Is there a way I can make the output of `listview.getItemAtPosition()` readable?

Code:

```
 public void blockCheckedItems(View view) {  
    // int cntChoice = lv.getCount();
     checked = new ArrayList<String>();
     unchecked = new ArrayList<String>();

    int itempositions=adapter.getCount();

    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    int countChoice = lv.getChildCount();

    Log.d("" + countChoice, "CountChoice===============================");
    Log.d("" + sparseBooleanArray,"sparseBooleanArray -------------------------");



     for(int i = 0; i < countChoice; i++)
     {

          if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
          {
              checked.add(lv.getItemAtPosition(i).
                      .toString());

          }
          else  if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) 
          {
              unchecked.add(lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
          }

      }
     for(int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++){
         Log.d("checked list&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&", "" + checked.get(i));
     }
     for(int i = 0; i < unchecked.size(); i++){
         Log.d("in unchecked list&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&", "" + unchecked.get(i));
     }


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When listview adapter is a `cursor adapter` then `listview.getItemAtPosition()` return a `cursor` pointed to that row. So you have to get data from that cursor like this:

```
Cursor cursor = listview.getItemAtPosition();
String name = cursor.getString(0);
```

I just assume that 0 is the index of `first name` column in that database which cursor is representing, It could be 2 , 3 ...

Comment: Thanks greatly for the help!! I was able to get it working thanks to the post! :D

Comment: Also, for some reason, it gives me random contact names in my unchecked list. For instance though I have Emily checked, and Matt Jones unchecked. It has both of them in the unchecked list. Is there any way I can solve this?